# Update row in excel when list control has filtered and distinct data

Tags: powerapps

I have a data model in excel with repeated rows by few columns. row update and delete is working if i don't apply filter or distinct in list control in prev screen.

How can i update selected row from prev screen list control when list control has filtered or distinct data.

my formula for filter as follows:

```
ShowColumns(
    Filter(
        Table2,
        Company = TemplateGalleryList1.Selected.Result,
        Department = TemplateGalleryList2.Selected.Result),
    "Team_x0020_Member_x0020_Email_x0020_Address",
    "Team_x0020_Member_x0020_Name",
    "Title",
    "Session_x0020_Date",
    "Session_x0020_Time")
```

i am attaching a excel data model here and in that model i am applying filter and distinct on company and department column.

[image]

Comment: If you only have filtered data (in a gallery, I assume), then updating the row should work, as the "shape" of the records isn't changed on a filter operation. What kind of error are you getting, and how are you trying to update the Excel row, using a form or the Patch function?

For Distinct data, what is the formula that you are using, and how are you trying to update the Excel row?

Comment: I am using form function to update data back. it's inserting a new row instead of update. I created 3 views. distinct companies are listed in first view. Distinct departments are listed in second view as per selected company from first view.  Filtered users are listed as per selected department and company.